# VB.Net Webpage login with IE

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, authentication

I'm trying to write a program that can manage my login's for work. I would use a WebBrowser control in my form but some of the locations only work in IE. I have gotten this to work in Excel with VBA, I'm just trying to move over to something that works a little quicker.

The code I have follows:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.name = "Name"
    Me.url = "web address"
    Me.log = "test"
    Me.pass = "test123"
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Login()
    Me.IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate(Me.url)
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> IE_READY.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
    IE.Visible = True
    'here is where it breaks
    IE.Document.GetElementsByName("username").SetAttribute("value", Me.log)
    IE.Document.GetElementsByName("password").SetAttribute("value", Me.pass)
End Sub
```

Everything works fine up till the point where I try to write to the log-in fields.

The HTML for the login field:

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="/Home/in">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="username" id="username" disabled="disabled" value="" />
    <label id="password-label" for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="validate[required]" name="password" id="password"  disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

`IE.Document.GetElementsByName("username").Value= Me.log`.

`IE.Document.GetElementsByName("password").Value= Me.pass`.

This may work for you